# Software Center Not Displaing Correctly

Tags: gnome, software-center

I'm not sure if I am asking this in the right place, I'm fairly new here. 
I recently installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 on my secondary laptop (Unity on my main). I'm having an issue with the Ubuntu Software Center not showing results correctly.

When I search for a package (such as Skype), the results show the Skype icon, but all of the text and information is blank.

Anyone have any ideas on what may be causing this?

Comment: Could this be a problem with themes? this might be helpful: http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2013-09/msg09060.html

Comment: Hmm, your comment made me re-check my themes. I had the Global Dark theme set with the Ubuntu tweak tool. I turned that off, and it fixed the issue. I wonder why that was causing it to not work correctly. It's a shame because I like the Global Dark theme. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: It's an old bug. I haven't seen the problem in recent distributions. (But I'm not running 14.10, but 14.04 Just a shot in the dark. I'm glad we hit the mark! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to System Settings -> Appearance

You'll see this:

[image: Themes]

Try going back to the Default theme.

If that doesn't resolve your issue try removing any third party themes you may have installed.

I can't verify as I"m not running 14.10 but it might be related to this bug http://osdir.com/ml/ubuntu-bugs/2013-09/msg09060.html

Comment: If it doesn't work, remove the acceptance check mark and downvote so no one else gets steered the wrong way. If it does work, upvote to help others find answers that work! I thank you and the community thanks you!

Comment: Your suggestion worked! The default theme fixed the issue. Thank you :)